# Why transfer function is implemented in constructor?

Tags: erc-20, ico, tokens

On ERC20 token implementation [example](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) on **wiki** they updated the code. And in constructor function of fixed token example they have used transfer function.

```
    function FixedSupplyToken() public {
    symbol = "FIXED";
    name = "Example Fixed Supply Token";
    decimals = 18;
    _totalSupply = 1000000 * 10**uint(decimals);
    balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
    Transfer(address(0), owner, _totalSupply);

}
```

Whats the significance of transfer function here and from where it is getting its parameters?

Answer (score 2):

`Transfer` is an event, not a function.

It's used here to make sure that tools that monitor for token transfer events see that the new token went to `owner`. It indicates that all the tokens were sent from address 0 to `owner`. (This isn't exactly accurate, since the tokens were never owned by address 0, but it seems to be a convention that quite a few tokens follow to show token creation.)

Comment: +1 for the part about convention. Always wondered why they are written like that.